# Define Object Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a page which has numerous articles. I want to give the user the ability to 'like' an article and to store that like id into a database for reuse later. Im new to Laravel and Php, so here is what i have.

I have models for Article and the Like. and i have this in the public store ArticleController.

```
public function store()
{
    $article = new Article();
    $article->body = 'new article body';
    $article->title = 'new article Title';
    $article->type = 'fashion';

    $article->save();

    $request = Request::all();

    $likes = new Like();
    $likes->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $likes->article_id = $article->id;
    $likes->save();

    return redirect('article');



}
```

I followed the tutorial on laravel fundamentals but i think i missed something. This is working for me here. But now i want to change it so that it only takes the existing article and does not make a new one. When i change it to reflect this:

```
$article = Article::find($id);
```

It tells me that the $id is not defined. So how do i make $id point to the article the user wants to 'like'?

Answer (score 0):

The question is `So how do i make $id point to the article the user wants to 'like'?`

This is quite a big/broad question but I'll try to sumarize. At first you need a route for that, for example:

```
Route::get('article/like/{id}', 'ArticleController@like');
```

Then in your `ArticleController` declare the `like` method, for example:

```
public function like($id)
{
    // Now you can use $id
}
```

To clarify you, `{id}` in the route will take the `id` of the article from the `URI` so you may use a `URI` like this:

```
http://example.com/article/like/10 // Here 10 is the article id
```

So this was the idea, now implement it and modify the `URI` or what ever you need to make it fit in your project but remember that, if you want to pass an id to your `URI` then you have to use a route parameter (i.e: `{id}` in this case) when declaring the route and your method should recieve that parameter using an argument in the method header, i.e: `public function like($id)`.